# echo sql result

Tags: php, sql, echo

i have a basic SQL query on a PHP webpage that i would like to echo out the result. i have tried the below but no cigar..

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "useraccounts");

$sql="SELECT expense FROM ctincome";

$results = mysqli_query($sql);
var_dump($results);
```

I am a novice at this, can anyone point out my mistake ?

Comment: try this, mysqli_query($link,$sql);

Comment: Tell us what result have you got

Comment: @Nunes Could you please let me know what notice you are showing?

Comment: my error is : Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Gosense/coaching.php on line 83
logo

Comment: @M.Hemant thanks tried that, the error has now changed to : object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Very Good @Nunes, Keep learning

Answer (score 0):

There might sql connection problem. Try this

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}
```